# How to say 'Just to add to that' in a meeting

Tags: word-choice

In a meeting, when someone has made a point and you want to add an additional comment to what was said, is there a way to say 'just to add to that...' or 'in addition to that...'?

Would it be something like それに言い添えて...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will hear all of the following:

・「（今{いま}の〇〇さんのご意見{いけん}/ご指摘{してき}に）付{つ}け加{くわ}えますと」

・「（もう）ひとつ付け加えますと」

・「ちなみに申{もう}しますと/申し上{あ}げますと」

・「ちなみにですが」

Note:  Depending on the situation, you will need to use 「〇〇[課長]{かちょう}」, 「〇〇[部長]{ぶちょう}」, etc. instead of 「〇〇さん」.